# Rails AJAX JS not being executed - Different case than all other topics

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a very frustrating error with Rails and AJAX.

There are a lot of topics on this matter here and I have looked through all of them rigorously, but my case seems truly different.

The situation:

I'm working with React and Rails (React on Rails gem) and from React I'm making an AJAX request to rails. The request is interpreted by Rails as JS.
Proof: `Processing by ShoppingCartItemsController#create as JS`

And after that:  `Rendered shopping_cart_items/create.js (0.3ms)`

The only line (at the moment) in my create.js is `console.log("hello world");` which obviously should not raise any errors. Looking at my Chrome inspector -> Network -> XHR -> Response I see this line being returned by the server. Even though it is being returned, there is still no log to the console.

My controller for reference:

```
def create
    @item = add_item_to_cart(params[:item], @cart)
    @cart.reload
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {
         render layout: false, content_type: 'text/javascript'
      }
    end
  end
```

I have also tried removing layout: false and content_type: text/javascript or one of both, but all without success.

I'm completely clueless on what could be the issue, everything seems to be working fine. When I stroll through the topics on SO, the only answers provided (and those answers seem to work for everyone) are, I believe, things I have already tried / that are in my code right now. That's why I'm opening a new subject on this topic.

The only thing I can think of is it has something to do with my integration of React (that seems to be the only point where my situation differs from the rest), but it seems weird because the JS console is not directly linked to React and therefore should not be influenced by its presence.

It would be extremely awesome if someone has a suggestion on how to fix / debug this. I've been stuck for days with this nasty issue.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it with React, but you have to actually append the response to the rails app itself if you want to render a partial... in create.js.erb you have to write `$(".divclass").append("<%= j render :partial => 'posts/partial.html.erb' %> ")`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I'm not looking to append partials or anything, just looking to make a console.log!